# How to aquire in Python the execution time of a gnuplot script?

Tags: python, time, gnuplot

I am quite new to Python and now I am trying to play a bit with it.
I want to import the execution time of a Gnuplot script in the following way:

```
 import os
 run_time = os.system("time gnuplot sript.gnuplot")
 print "run time:",run_time
```

What I get is this:

```
run time: 256
```

It's zero if has nothing to run and 256 if it's doing something. 
The type of run_time is int and I was trying to get this kind of string

```
0.65user 0.06system 0:00.72elapsed
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong at this point, but I will continue to look into it.

My question is if there is another way to measure this execution time or if I can correct my code some way.

The point of all this is that I want to use this time as a pause in the python script so I can let Gnuplot enough time to fit my data. If I import the gnuplot library in python I don't know exactly how much time do I need to fit every plot that I want so I don't want to stop the process and get a bad fit.(e.g. I think if I use pause is a bad idea because for every set of data points that I simulate and then try to fit, the time necessary until the fit is done, is different for each plot). I hope I made the problem as clear as possible!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to pause Python? Calling [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) will wait until it has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The `os.system` function gives you the return code of the program, not the string it sent to its output.

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead for launching gnuplot:

```
import subprocess
run_time_str = subprocess.check_output(['time', 'gnuplot', 'sript.gnuplot'])
print 'run time:', run_time_str
```

You can also measure the time directly in Python using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module:

```
import subprocess
from timeit import timeit
run_time = timeit(lambda: subprocess.call(['gnuplot', 'sript.gnuplot']), number=1)
print 'run_time: %.1f milliseconds' % (run_time*1000)
```

Note that this gives you the runtime as a number, whereas you would have to extract it from `time`'s output string (`0.65user 0.06system 0:00.72elapsed`) yourself.

Comment: Way better! As you have anticipated, I wanted to manipulate the string, which would have been an unnecessary hassle.